# Solution For This npm ERR! could not determine executable to run?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npx

```
npx mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://taherbalasinorwalaofficial:<MY PASSWORD>@cluster0.zh0w8hr.mongodb.net --collection products --type json --file ./static/products.json --jsonArray
>>
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

I tried installing mongodb, mongodbtools but still not worked.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `npx` at all? [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) is a separate CLI tool, nothing to do with [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoimport).

Comment: i want to run this in vs code terminal to import products  into my database , Can you provide me some steps how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can very well import products into your database using mongoimport.

Please take note, as @jonrsharpe has commented, mongoimport is a command line utility. You can run it either from command line of your operating system or from   vscode terminal. Please do note that you simply give the following command which has only one difference from your version of code. The prefix npx is removed. The reason for this change is that npx is another command line utility, as you might know, it is used for npm packages updating.

In short, the command you try now is having two commands used for two different purposes. Therefore please change it as it has been explained.

mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://taherbalasinorwalaofficial:@cluster0.zh0w8hr.mongodb.net --collection products --type json --file ./static/products.json --jsonArray

Thanks
WoDoTheBest4You

Comment: mongoimport : The term 'mongoimport' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.  I used only mongoimport function in vs code terminal it shows above error.